# Javascript Node.js get all the specific array value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

This part of code only shows the first and second person in the database "Ban" status.

```
console.log("Banned0",res.data.data[0].banned); //display the first person banned status
console.log("Banned1",res.data.data[1].banned);  //display the second person banned status
```

[image]

I would like to console.log all 5 person banned status without repeatedly using console.log.

Comment: `res.data.map(item => console.log(item.data.banned))` should do it. :)

Comment: That's not what `map` is meant to be used for. Try `forEach` or `for...of`.

Comment: Ok then. `res.data.forEach` - Happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution, using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
res.data.data.forEach((data, idx) => console.log('Banned' + idx, data.banned));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you find an array, you must looping the data, u can use this function

```
array.map(data => console.log(data));
or
array.forEach((data) => console.log(data));
```

Read this articles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration?retiredLocale=id

Comment: as Andy said in another comment ... don't use map

Answer (score 3):

You can use any kind of `for` loop to iterate over the data.

My suggestion is to either use a for of loop:

```js
for (const dataItem of res.data.data) {
    console.log("Banned", dataItem.banned);
}
```

or a forEach loop on the array, which would also easily get you the index:

```js
res.data.data.forEach((dataItem, index) => {
    console.log(`Banned ${index}`, dataItem.banned);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is to finding a way to iterate over an array of objects each with a banned status. There are a few ways to approach this.

You could use the old-school [`for statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#examples):

```js
const res={data:{data:[{banned:true,name:"Bob"},{banned:true,name:"Zoe"},{banned:true,name:"Gary"},{banned:false,name:"Fred"}]}};

for (let i = 0; i < res.data.data.length; i++) {
  const { name, banned } = res.data.data[i];
  console.log(`Is ${name} banned? ${banned}`);
}
```

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). (Note: the limitation of `forEach` is you can't return a value early if, for example, your loop was in a function, or `break` or `continue`).

```js
const res={data:{data:[{banned:true,name:"Bob"},{banned:true,name:"Zoe"},{banned:true,name:"Gary"},{banned:false,name:"Fred"}]}};

res.data.data.forEach(user => {
  const { name, banned } = user;
  console.log(`Is ${name} banned? ${banned}`);
});
```

Finally here's [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement):

```js
const res={data:{data:[{banned:true,name:"Bob"},{banned:true,name:"Zoe"},{banned:true,name:"Gary"},{banned:false,name:"Fred"}]}};

for (const user of res.data.data) {
  const { name, banned } = user;
  console.log(`Is ${name} banned? ${banned}`);
}
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)